# Laravel render 500 page instead welcome view

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a new laravel project using `laravel new` and did `composer updadte`. I hosted the site on localhost.

But it renders a `500` page instead of welcome screen.
I also changed the function in route in *web.php* to this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "hello world";
});
```

But it is not showing even this.

Comment: Could be a multitude of factors. What's your local hosting; XAMPP, Vagrant, Docker? What does your Hosts file look like if so?

Comment: Do you have debug turned on? Should be a couple settings in `.env` to handle that (`APP_DEBUG=true` being the primary). If that still doesn't help, make sure your `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders are writable, and check your web server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. Change .env.example to .env and generate the encryption key. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

You need to check error logs on your application or server. For your error logs in Laravel 5 check `config/logging.php` to know where Laravel is writing logs to.

Answer (score 0):

Set chmod 777 storage and bootstrap/cache

Ex:

sudo chmod -R 777 storage

sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache